Are name changes listed and available to users?
If a user changes their display name on Stack Exchange can other users check back and see what name that user used previously ?

I don't think so (for non-mods). But sometimes you can check their accounts on other SE sites, as they may not have changed their username on each one.

Yes indeed, and I have found older names on Stack Overflow and Chat.
